# How to draw string to a bitmap image in WinRT

Tags: c#, image, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winjs

How do you draw a string to an image in `winRT`? In WinForms that could be done using `drawstring()` method inside the `system.drawing` namespace but i couldn't find its equivalent in WinRT API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct2D is a replacement for GDI in WinRT. So you'll have to use C++/CX with DirectX for drawing text.

I don't have any examples for you, but maybe [this link](http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/categories/metro/nativecode.aspx?ID=02e3515b-5cfd-4f57-aad5-897a9f418878) (and the links included) can help you on your way.

Comment: @fire'fly I know, but unfortunately that's not possible as for now. But at least there is a solution for WinRT, in general, with Direct2D.

Comment: So now we can't draw some text without C++! Well done Microsoft!

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 8.1 they finally support rendering of XAML controls to bitmap. Now you can use

```
var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(uiElement, width, height));
var buffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
var tmpWbm = new WriteableBitmap(renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth, renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use DirectX. You can do so in C# by using [SharpDx](http://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't - there is unfortunately no such API :-(

Answer (score 0):

Google for 'Metro CSharp using Direct2D and DirectWrite for Graphics'. It's one of their code samples. It's not the most concise example I've ever seen, but it does work. Using SharpDX to do the same thing will be cleaner.

Comment: Be great if you explained what you found too