# windows 8 metro app converts text to image

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, .net-4.5

Is there a way to convert text to an image with Windows store app API?

The analogous code in a normal windows app would be:

```
graphics.DrawString(txt, font, Brushes, 0, 0);
```

Comment: You would need to use something like http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ in order to acomplish this. Based on my research you might even have to extend that project to acomplish this. Although I highly suspect converting the string to a byte[] and writting the byte[] to the Image would acomplish what you want.  Of course this also has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005424/how-to-draw-string-to-a-bitmap-image-in-winrt#